# Bayesian two way test-results interpretation

Tags: bayesian, python

I did a bayesian two way hypothesis test using pymc3 - the variable "do you like chemical free products - yes/no" vs "will you buy this soap or not". The goal was to understand if those who like chemical free products are more likely to buy it or not? The code is below and I am not able to interpret results show in table. What is the conclusion?

```
import pymc3 as pm
import numpy as np


# Convert data to NumPy array
data = np.array([left_merged['chemical_free'], 
                 left_merged['purchaseDecision_soap']]).T

# Define the model
with pm.Model() as model:
    # Priors
    p_val_yes = pm.Beta('p_val_yes', alpha=1, beta=1)
    p_val_no = pm.Beta('p_val_no', alpha=1, beta=1)
    
    # Likelihood
    y = pm.Bernoulli('y', p=p_val_yes if data[:,0] == '1' else p_val_no, observed=data[:,1])
    
    # Sample from the posterior distribution
    trace = pm.sample(draws=5000, tune=1000, chains=2)

# Extract the values of p_val_yes and p_val_no from the trace
p_val_yes_samples = trace['p_val_yes']
p_val_no_samples = trace['p_val_no']

# Calculate the difference in purchase proportions between val_yes and val_no
delta = p_val_yes_samples - p_val_no_samples

# Calculate the credible interval for delta
az.summary(trace)

mean          sd    hdi_3%  hdi_97% mcse_mean   mcse_sd    ess_bulk ess_tail r_hat
p_val_yes   0.506   0.289   0.026   0.964   0.004   0.003   6609.0  6548.0  1.0
p_val_no    0.645   0.028   0.589   0.695   0.000   0.000   7168.0  6979.0  1.0
```

Comment: How did you write the model then? What model did you want to create, why? By the looks of it you are getting posterior predictive for difference between yes/no rates. Imagine you have it, what do you expect to see there? The code itself is pretty simple, so your question is probably more about the logic, rather than results

Comment: The goal was to understand if those who like chemical free products are more likely to buy it or not?

Comment: Why did you define p_val_yes and p_val_no? Are these not mutually exclusive? In your questionnaire can the person give mixed answer or is it yes/no? I repeat the logic is simpl

Comment: IMHO all you need is the probability distribution for rate of people liking the product, and then you can link inference to saying something like, any random person from target population is X% likely to like the product (essentially a posterior predictive of a YES)

Comment: each participant can only choose either yes or no. so how to do it in python? what changes to make in the code?

Comment: Not sure this a good way to approach this? Whether you need it for work/education/self-study, do you want some random person to simply tell you what is 'right'? Or do you want to understand what you are doing? So it is better to focus on the question you are trying to ask and trying to answer. Code is secondary, in fact, I think you may be even able to do it analytically

Comment: Imagine you have distribution of probability of a yes, e.g. 30% of population will say yes with probability of 0.3, 20% of population will say yes with probability of  0.4, and 50% of population will say yes with probability of 0.8. How will you get your answer from it?

Comment: by calculating - a randomly selected person will have what probability of saying yes